# The difference Loads of, much, and a lot of

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I have problem to determine which one is more suitable to use as I've already mentioned in the title of the question.

Consider these sentences below, which one sounds good?

1. I can't go tonight, I have loads of work to do.
2. I can't go tonight, I have much work to do.
3. I can't go tonight, I have a lot of work to do.

I've heard of **lots of**, is this the same as **loads of**? I want to assure whether they sound good or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, UK speakers would likely say “loads of work” while that would be less common in the US, where “a lot of work” or “lots of work” are more used. In either case, “much work” sounds stilted and probably wouldn’t be used very often, at least in conversation.

Comment: Agreed, and "much" is only used when it is further modified by a negative, or "too much" or "so much" etc., so in this case, it sounds awkward

Comment: Even in the UK, _loads of_ would only be used in informal conversation.